# How to adjust space between radio button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

In my android application using radio buttons to select screen view. I want radio button equally aligned horizontal.  I tried layout xml shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Views"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioViewSingle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/single"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioView2by2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/view2x2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioView3by3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/view3x3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioView4by4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/view4x4" />
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
output obtained using above xml code

But i expecting below output

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using android:drawableRight, use android:drawableLeft.

I just tested this and it is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Remove **android:layout_weight="1"** for all **RadioButtons** and set **android:layout_width="0dp"** to **android:layout_width="wrap_content"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Views"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioViewSingle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioView2by2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioView3by3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_always_landscape_portrait" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioView4by4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hope this will help you :)

Comment: After implementing your solution radio button is ok.  But how can i equally distribute radio buttons across the view.  show in above picture

Comment: for that you have to implement a separate layout for each radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

You can put each RadioButton to one layout and give all layout_width="0dp" and give layout_weight="1" as showen below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/single"
            android:id="@+id/radioViewSingle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/view2x2"
            android:id="@+id/radioView2by2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/view3x3"
            android:id="@+id/radioView3by3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/view4x4"
            android:id="@+id/radioView4by4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Hope this will helps to you.

Comment: Updating with your solution. all the radio buttons are checked.  Kindly change "androd:gravity="left" to "android:gravity="left"